# Why does ChangeWindowMessageFilter cause Qt to crash?

Tags: c++, c, qt, dynamic-loading

Why does the following program crash?

```
#include <QApplication>

#include <windows.h>
#include <QFrame>


uint MSGFLT_ADD = 1;
uint WM_COPYGLOBALDATA = 0x0049;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    BOOL (*ChangeWindowMessageFilter)(UINT,DWORD) = NULL;

    HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibraryA("User32.dll");               // Handle to DLL
    if (hDLL != NULL){
        ChangeWindowMessageFilter = (BOOL (*)(UINT,DWORD))GetProcAddress(hDLL, "ChangeWindowMessageFilter");
    }

    if (ChangeWindowMessageFilter != NULL){
        if (!(*ChangeWindowMessageFilter)(WM_DROPFILES, MSGFLT_ADD)){
            printf("Failed to add exception for WM_DROPFILES\n");
        }
        if (!(*ChangeWindowMessageFilter)(WM_COPYDATA, MSGFLT_ADD)){
            printf("Failed to add exception for WM_COPYDATA");
        }
        if (!(*ChangeWindowMessageFilter)(WM_COPYGLOBALDATA, MSGFLT_ADD)){
            printf("Failed to add exception for WM_COPYGLOBALDATA");
        }
        printf("Added filters\n");
        fflush(0);
    }
    if (hDLL != NULL){
        FreeLibrary(hDLL);
    }

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QFrame w; //debug crashes here
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

```
QFrame::QFrame(QWidget* parent, Qt::WindowFlags f)
    : QWidget(*new QFramePrivate, parent, f) //on this line in particular
{
    Q_D(QFrame);
    d->init();
}
```

EDIT:

```
if (!(*ChangeWindowMessageFilter)(WM_COPYDATA, MSGFLT_ADD)){ //if i disable this everything works
    printf("Failed to add exception for WM_COPYDATA");
}
```

Comment: Is your output set to 64 bit or 32 bit?

Comment: thats a good question, it is 32 bit. am i perhaps loading a 64 bit version?

Comment: Is your Windows 64-bit?

Comment: @Extrakun that is not the issue, see edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   BOOL (*ChangeWindowMessageFilter)(UINT,DWORD) = NULL;
```

Your function pointer declaration is wrong.  Winapi functions are always __stdcall.  Your compiler no doubt uses the default, __cdecl.  The stack imbalance you get when you make the call through the function pointer can have many side effects.  If you use MSVC++ and run the Debug build then you'll always get an immediate diagnostic.  Fix:

```
   BOOL (WINAPI * ChangeWindowMessageFilter)(UINT,DWORD) = NULL;
```

Fwiw, if this is meant to enable drag+drop into an elevated program then just remove all this, it won't work.  D+D is COM based, it doesn't use messages.

Comment: Ah, thanks. It is meant to enable DnD (and didnt work, haha). Is there a workaround to enable it?

Comment: Google "uiaccess = true"